# Encoding of list of sum of 2 dice that has better compression. (byte restricted)

Tags: algorithm, compression

Imagine any game in which two six-sided dice are used.

It is needed to store the history of the game, we want to store the sums resulting from rolling the dice in the whole game.

In traditional Huffman enconding, 7 has bigger probability, so , it is encoded in 3 bits. 2 and 12 need 5 bits.
In this case, one symbol is encoded in variable code size.

However, I'm trying to figure out an enconding in which a single byte (8 bits) encode a different sequence of sum of dice.
So, in this case, the code size is constant (8 bits) , but the number of symbols is variable. Naive Example:

- 0x00 = {2}
- 0x01 = {3}
- ...
- 0x0A = {12}
- 0x0B = {2,2}
- 0x0C = {2,3}
- 0x0D = {2,4} etc.

So, the decoder can read byte by byte. Therefore each byte is independent of the other.

How to find the mapping that has the better compression?

Can you point to some algorithm that solves this case of compression?

My thoughts about this is:

Sequence of 1 sum can be assigned from 0x00 to 0x0A (from 2 to 12).
I can split the sequence {7} into: {7,1} , {7,2} ... {7,12} and assign values for these sequences.

If I do this for the whole list of {7,x}, then, I could remove {7} from the 1 sum values (because any sequence which starts by 7 is reachable by using the 2 sum sequences).
So, the resulting encoding would be:

- {2} - {6}
- {8} - {12}
- {7,2} - {7,12}

Then, for example, I think: {6,6} , {6,7} or {6,8} could provide more "value" (bigger probability) than {7,2} or {7,12}.

But, if I remove {7,2} or {7,12}, then, I should return {7} to the list (otherwise, {7,2} could not be expressed).
Something like this:

- {2} - {12}
- {7,3} - {7,11}
- {6,6} - {6,8}

So, there should be some kind of "trade-off" in this problem.

Comment: To be honest, I do not understand you syntax. But your results from one roll all fit into 4 bits (2...12), so you can store 2 rolls in one byte. Now you can run LZH on those bytes. Compression ratio is dependent on the equal-sequence length and the amount of equals pair-rolls (how often did you roll (1,4) in the history). Probability of rolling the same two-dice rolls again is ... something I cannot calculate right now :-)

Comment: Definitely don't use LZH. Do you insist on a byte-by-byte encoding or is word-by-word OK as long as we don't need a big table?

Comment: Does the sequence of bytes need to be self-terminating?

Comment: No need to be self-terminating. The number of rolls is stored somewhere else.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a solution that I think achieves rate approximately 7.733629 bits per byte. (Generating code in Python 3, if you want to play with it: https://github.com/eisenstatdavid/huffman/blob/master/huffman.py) My algorithm is some [EM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Expectation%E2%80%93maximization_algorithm)ish thing that alternately (1) computes the stationary distribution of the first roll in a byte (2) chooses the most 256 probable words subject to the constraint that we can encode any infinite sequence. I would conjecture optimality, though I know only that this solution is a local maximum (and even then, assuming my code has no bugs, etc.).

```
{{2}, {12}, {7, 7}, {6, 7}, {8, 7}, {5, 7}, {9, 7}, {4, 7}, {10,
7}, {7, 6}, {7, 8}, {6, 6}, {6, 8}, {8, 6}, {8, 8}, {5, 6}, {5, 8},
{9, 6}, {9, 8}, {4, 6}, {4, 8}, {10, 6}, {10, 8}, {7, 5}, {7, 9},
{6, 5}, {6, 9}, {8, 5}, {8, 9}, {5, 5}, {5, 9}, {9, 5}, {9, 9}, {3,
7}, {11, 7}, {4, 5}, {4, 9}, {10, 5}, {10, 9}, {7, 4}, {7, 10}, {3,
6}, {3, 8}, {11, 6}, {11, 8}, {6, 4}, {6, 10}, {8, 4}, {8, 10}, {5,
4}, {5, 10}, {9, 4}, {9, 10}, {4, 4}, {4, 10}, {10, 4}, {10, 10},
{3, 5}, {3, 9}, {11, 5}, {11, 9}, {7, 3}, {7, 11}, {2, 7}, {12, 7},
{6, 3}, {6, 11}, {8, 3}, {8, 11}, {5, 3}, {5, 11}, {9, 3}, {9, 11},
{3, 4}, {3, 10}, {11, 4}, {11, 10}, {4, 3}, {4, 11}, {10, 3}, {10,
11}, {2, 6}, {2, 8}, {12, 6}, {12, 8}, {2, 5}, {2, 9}, {12, 5},
{12, 9}, {3, 3}, {3, 11}, {11, 3}, {11, 11}, {7, 2}, {7, 12}, {7,
7, 7}, {2, 4}, {2, 10}, {12, 4}, {12, 10}, {6, 2}, {6, 12}, {8, 2},
{8, 12}, {6, 7, 7}, {8, 7, 7}, {5, 2}, {5, 12}, {9, 2}, {9, 12},
{5, 7, 7}, {9, 7, 7}, {4, 2}, {4, 12}, {10, 2}, {10, 12}, {4, 7,
7}, {10, 7, 7}, {7, 6, 7}, {7, 7, 6}, {7, 7, 8}, {7, 8, 7}, {6, 6,
7}, {6, 8, 7}, {8, 6, 7}, {8, 8, 7}, {6, 7, 6}, {6, 7, 8}, {8, 7,
6}, {8, 7, 8}, {5, 6, 7}, {5, 7, 6}, {5, 7, 8}, {5, 8, 7}, {9, 6,
7}, {9, 7, 6}, {9, 7, 8}, {9, 8, 7}, {4, 6, 7}, {4, 7, 6}, {4, 7,
8}, {4, 8, 7}, {10, 6, 7}, {10, 7, 6}, {10, 7, 8}, {10, 8, 7}, {7,
6, 6}, {7, 6, 8}, {7, 8, 6}, {7, 8, 8}, {7, 5, 7}, {7, 7, 5}, {7,
7, 9}, {7, 9, 7}, {6, 6, 6}, {6, 6, 8}, {6, 8, 6}, {6, 8, 8}, {8,
6, 6}, {8, 6, 8}, {8, 8, 6}, {8, 8, 8}, {5, 6, 6}, {5, 6, 8}, {5,
8, 6}, {5, 8, 8}, {9, 6, 6}, {9, 6, 8}, {9, 8, 6}, {9, 8, 8}, {2,
3}, {2, 11}, {12, 3}, {12, 11}, {6, 5, 7}, {6, 7, 5}, {6, 7, 9},
{6, 9, 7}, {8, 5, 7}, {8, 7, 5}, {8, 7, 9}, {8, 9, 7}, {5, 5, 7},
{5, 7, 5}, {5, 7, 9}, {5, 9, 7}, {9, 5, 7}, {9, 7, 5}, {9, 7, 9},
{9, 9, 7}, {4, 6, 6}, {4, 6, 8}, {4, 8, 6}, {4, 8, 8}, {10, 6, 6},
{10, 6, 8}, {10, 8, 6}, {10, 8, 8}, {3, 2}, {3, 12}, {11, 2}, {11,
12}, {3, 7, 7}, {11, 7, 7}, {4, 5, 7}, {4, 7, 5}, {4, 7, 9}, {4,
9, 7}, {10, 5, 7}, {10, 7, 5}, {10, 7, 9}, {10, 9, 7}, {7, 5, 6},
{7, 5, 8}, {7, 9, 6}, {7, 9, 8}, {7, 6, 5}, {7, 6, 9}, {7, 8, 5},
{7, 8, 9}, {6, 6, 5}, {6, 6, 9}, {6, 8, 5}, {6, 8, 9}, {8, 6, 5},
{8, 6, 9}, {8, 8, 5}, {8, 8, 9}, {6, 5, 6}, {6, 5, 8}, {6, 9, 6},
{6, 9, 8}, {8, 5, 6}, {8, 5, 8}, {8, 9, 6}, {8, 9, 8}, {5, 5, 6},
{5, 5, 8}, {5, 6, 5}, {5, 6, 9}, {5, 8, 5}, {5, 8, 9}, {5, 9, 6},
{5, 9, 8}, {9, 5, 6}, {9, 5, 8}, {9, 6, 5}, {9, 6, 9}, {9, 8, 5},
{9, 8, 9}, {9, 9, 6}, {9, 9, 8}, {7, 4, 7}, {7, 7, 4}, {7, 7, 10},
{7, 10, 7}}
```

There's a simpler, suboptimal solution that packs about 7.438148 bits of entropy into a byte. The 251 codewords are all length-3 sequences that start with {5, 7}, {6, 6}, {6, 7}, {6, 8}, {7, 5}, {7, 6}, {7, 7}, {7, 8}, {7, 9}, {8, 6}, {8, 7}, {8, 8}, {9, 7}, plus all length-2 sequences that don't start with one of those prefixes.

Chart of whether to take the third roll given the first two:

```
   2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10 11 12
 2 -  -  -  -  -  -  -  -  -  -  -
 3 -  -  -  -  -  -  -  -  -  -  -
 4 -  -  -  -  -  -  -  -  -  -  -
 5 -  -  -  -  -  X  -  -  -  -  -
 6 -  -  -  -  X  X  X  -  -  -  -
 7 -  -  -  X  X  X  X  X  -  -  -
 8 -  -  -  -  X  X  X  -  -  -  -
 9 -  -  -  -  -  X  -  -  -  -  -
10 -  -  -  -  -  -  -  -  -  -  -
11 -  -  -  -  -  -  -  -  -  -  -
12 -  -  -  -  -  -  -  -  -  -  -
```

It's hard to analyze solutions where the encoder might or might not pack the next roll depending on what it is -- the probability distribution next time is affected.

Comment: Hi David. I'm not familiar with python. I've tried to run your program, but I got: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "huffman.py", line 157, in <module>
    main()
  File "huffman.py", line 124, in main
    pdict = eigen(symset, words)
  File "huffman.py", line 113, in eigen
    assert 1 - 1e-9 <= d <= 1 + 1e-9
AssertionError

I added:
print qdict
print qdict.values()
print d

right before the assert, and looks like everything is 0

Comment: @AbrahamSanchez Probably you're using Python 2 instead of Python 3.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are interested in the sum, not in the sequence:
Variable length: Huffman
{2: 01110, 3: 0110, 4: 1100, 5: 000, 6: 001, 7: 010, 8: 100, 9: 101, 10: 111, 11: 1101, 12: 01111};
For fixed length: look for Tunstall coding

Comment: The OP already demonstrated knowing about the  Huffman encoding, and their question is not what that encoding would be. A reference to Tunstall coding may be valid, but can you provide in your answer a short description of that compression method and why it is the better compression?